# R Gibbs Sampler for Bayesian Regression

Tags: r

I am trying to code a Gibbs sampler for a Bayesian regression model in R, and I am having trouble running my code.  It seems there is something going on with the beta in the sigma.update function.  When I run the code I get an error that says " Error in x %*% beta : non-conformable arguments"  Here is what my code looks like:

```
x0 <- rep(1, 1000)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, 5, 7)
x <- cbind(x0, x1)
true_error <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
true_beta <- c(1.1, -8.2)
y <- x %*% true_beta + true_error

beta0 <- c(1, 1)
sigma0 <- 1  
a <- b <- 1
burnin <- 0
thin <- 1
n <- 100

gibbs <- function(n.sims, beta.start, a, b,
                  y, x, burnin, thin) {
   beta.draws <- matrix(NA, nrow=n.sims, ncol=1)
   sigma.draws<- c()
   beta.cur <- beta.start
   sigma.update <- function(a,b, beta, y, x) {
        1 / rgamma(1, a + ((length(x)) / 2),
                   b + (1 / 2) %*% (t(y - x %*% beta) %*% (y - x %*% beta)))
     }
   beta.update <- function(x, y, sigma) {
        rnorm(1, (solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% y),
              sigma^2 * (solve(t(x) %*%x)))
     }
   for (i in 1:n.sims) {
     sigma.cur <- sigma.update(a, b, beta.cur, y, x)
     beta.cur <- beta.update(x, y, sigma.cur)
     if (i > burnin & (i - burnin) %% thin == 0) {
       sigma.draws[(i - burnin) / thin ] <- sigma.cur
       beta.draws[(i - burnin) / thin,] <- beta.cur
       }
     }
   return (list(sigma.draws, beta.draws) )
   }

gibbs(n, beta0, a, b, y, x, burnin, thin)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! I added few spaces to your code to make it more readable. Also, consider using `r` tag since it is R-related question.

Comment: And your error suggests that you probably forgot to transpose something - sorry I don't have time now to review the code.

Comment: 1) `beta.draws` should be a two-column matrix and `beta.update` should generate two values, use `rnorm(2,...)`. This will solve the error but you should still check that the equations and the results are correct. 2) Tip: use the functions `crossprod` or `tcrossprod` for matrix products of the kind X'X or XX'.

Comment: @javlacalle I fixed what you mentioned, and I was able to fix the error I was receiving, but now the output is NaN for all but the first entry in both the sigma.draws and beta.draws.  Any idea what else is going wrong? Thank again by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `beta.update` is not correct, it returns `NaN`. You are defining a matrix in the argument `sd` that is passed to `rnorm`, a vector is expected in this argument. I think what you are trying to do could be done in this way:

```
beta.update <- function(x, y, sigma) {
  rn <- rnorm(n=2, mean=0, sd=sigma)
  xtxinv <- solve(crossprod(x))
  as.vector(xtxinv %*% crossprod(x, y)) + xtxinv %*% rn
}
```

Notice that you are computing some elements that are fixed at all iterations. For example, you could define `t(x) %*% x` once and pass this element as argument to other functions. In this way you avoid doing these operations at every iteration, saving some computations and probably some time.

**Edit**

Based on your code, this is what I do:

```
x0 <- rep(1, 1000)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, 5, 7)
x <- cbind(x0, x1)
true_error <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
true_beta <- c(1.1, -8.2)
y <- x %*% true_beta + true_error

beta0 <- c(1, 1)
sigma0 <- 1  
a <- b <- 1
burnin <- 0
thin <- 1
n <- 100

gibbs <- function(n.sims, beta.start, a, b, y, x, burnin, thin) 
{
  beta.draws <- matrix(NA, nrow=n.sims, ncol=2)
  sigma.draws<- c()
  beta.cur <- beta.start
  sigma.update <- function(a,b, beta, y, x) {
    1 / rgamma(1, a + ((length(x)) / 2),
    b + (1 / 2) %*% (t(y - x %*% beta) %*% (y - x %*% beta)))
  }
  beta.update <- function(x, y, sigma) {
    rn <- rnorm(n=2, mean=0, sd=sigma)
    xtxinv <- solve(crossprod(x))
    as.vector(xtxinv %*% crossprod(x, y)) + xtxinv %*% rn
  }
  for (i in 1:n.sims) {
    sigma.cur <- sigma.update(a, b, beta.cur, y, x)
     beta.cur <- beta.update(x, y, sigma.cur)
     if (i > burnin & (i - burnin) %% thin == 0) {
       sigma.draws[(i - burnin) / thin ] <- sigma.cur
       beta.draws[(i - burnin) / thin,] <- beta.cur
     }
  }
  return (list(sigma.draws, beta.draws) )
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
set.seed(123)
res <- gibbs(n, beta0, a, b, y, x, burnin, thin)
head(res[[1]])
# [1] 3015.256257   13.632748    1.950697    1.861225    1.928381    1.884090
tail(res[[1]])
# [1] 1.887497 1.915900 1.984031 2.010798 1.888575 1.994850
head(res[[2]])
#          [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 7.135294 -8.697288
# [2,] 1.040720 -8.193057
# [3,] 1.047058 -8.193531
# [4,] 1.043769 -8.193183
# [5,] 1.043766 -8.193279
# [6,] 1.045247 -8.193356
tail(res[[2]])
#            [,1]      [,2]
# [95,]  1.048501 -8.193550
# [96,]  1.037859 -8.192848
# [97,]  1.045809 -8.193377
# [98,]  1.045611 -8.193374
# [99,]  1.038800 -8.192880
# [100,] 1.047063 -8.193479
```

Comment: So the code works, but I am still unclear as to why the beta.update function is not using the sigma.cur value when generating new beta?  Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the gibbs sampler?

Comment: You are right, `sigma` must be used in `beta.update`. I changed the code including `sigma` as the standard deviation od the Gaussian draw. But you should check that this agrees with the expressions from a textbook or other source about Gibbs sampling and linear regression. I just checked that the dimension of each element is correct.

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.